# Can Quartz Scheduler (cron) schedule multiple jobs at the same execution time?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm planning to use the Quartz cron scheduler for scheduling jobs. My scheduling pattern might require multiple jobs (say A, B, C) to be able to run at the same time (say every 10 minute both A and B should run in parallel). Right now, the way I see it Quartz seem to limit this functionality. I use Spring Framework.

Question - Can schedules created/ implemented using [Quartz Cron](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) be able to run multiple jobs at the same execution time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can configure the threadCount property on Quartzs [scheduler thread pool](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool):

> org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount
>
> Can be any positive integer, although you should realize that only
>   numbers between 1 and 100 are very practical. **This is the number of
>   threads that are available for concurrent execution of jobs.** If you
>   only have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then 1 thread is
>   plenty! If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many firing every
>   minute, then you probably want a thread count more like 50 or 100
>   (this highly depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform,
>   and your systems resources!).